# Explain left child right sibling traversal

Tags: c++, tree

I have a left child right sibling as below:

```
    10 
*    | 
*    2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 
*              |    | 
*              6    7 -> 8 -> 9  */
```

I want to traverse from root to the last node, the traversal function is as below:

```
void traverseTree(Node * root) 
{ 
    if (root == NULL) 
        return; 

    while (root) 
    { 
        cout << " " << root->data; 
        if (root->child) 
            traverseTree(root->child); 
        root = root->next; 
    } 
}
```

As I understood, if the node has a child, then the pointer points to its child, otherwise points to the sibling (next). In this case, when the pointer points to element 6, it will go to the root->next element (which is NULL). However, the function can still be able to print the remaining element (5,7,8,9). Can any one help me explain how  `traverseTree` works?

Here's the code to recreate the tree:

```
// CPP program to create a tree with left child 
// right sibling representation. 
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

struct Node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct Node *next; 
    struct Node *child; 
}; 

// Creating new Node 
Node* newNode(int data) 
{ 
    Node *newNode = new Node; 
    newNode->next = newNode->child = NULL; 
    newNode->data = data; 
    return newNode; 
} 

// Adds a sibling to a list with starting with n 
Node *addSibling(Node *n, int data) 
{ 
    if (n == NULL) 
        return NULL; 

    while (n->next) 
        n = n->next; 

    return (n->next = newNode(data)); 
} 

// Add child Node to a Node 
Node *addChild(Node * n, int data) 
{ 
    if (n == NULL) 
        return NULL; 

    // Check if child list is not empty. 
    if (n->child) 
        return addSibling(n->child, data); 
    else
        return (n->child = newNode(data)); 
} 

// Traverses tree in level order 
void traverseTree(Node * root) 
{ 
    if (root == NULL) 
        return; 

    while (root) 
    { 
        cout << " " << root->data; 
        if (root->child) 
            traverseTree(root->child); 
        root = root->next; 
    } 
} 

//Driver code 

int main() 
{ 
    Node *root = newNode(10); 
    Node *n1 = addChild(root, 2); 
    Node *n2 = addChild(root, 3); 
    Node *n3 = addChild(root, 4); 
    Node *n4 = addChild(n3, 6); 
    Node *n5 = addChild(root, 5); 
    Node *n6 = addChild(n5, 7); 
    Node *n7 = addChild(n5, 8); 
    Node *n8 = addChild(n5, 9); 
    traverseTree(root); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After executing `traverseTree(root->child)` the control flow will continue from the next line. You're not returning from the function, just calling another function from within this function.

```
void traverseTree(Node * root) 
{ 
    if (root == NULL) 
        return; 

    while (root) 
    { 
        cout << " " << root->data; 
        if (root->child) 
            traverseTree(root->child); // First, if child exists, traverse child. No return statement following here.
        root = root->next; // Next, traverse sibling
    } 
}
```

If you still have doubts it would do you good to read about the program flow when calling a function.

**Update(completely irrelevant to the question):** As requested by OP, [solution using stack](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BZzT3ebcs31Wh6u1):

```
void traverseTree(Node * root) 
{ 
    if (root == NULL) 
        return; 
    stack<Node*> s;
    s.push(root);
    while (!s.empty())
    {
        Node* top = s.top();
        cout << " " << top->data;
        s.pop();
        if (top->next) s.push(top->next);
        if (top->child) s.push(top->child);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to implement this without recursion?

Comment: @HaAnTran Yes. All recursive functions can be written without recursion by using a stack data structure.

Comment: @HaAnTran Yes. This is a simple DFS. You can do it using a stack.

Comment: @theWiseBro is there any example/pseudocode for my case using stack?

Comment: @HaAnTran take this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/BZzT3ebcs31Wh6u1 . Also added to the answer.

Comment: @theWiseBro do both methods have equal time complexity O(n)?

Comment: @HaAnTran yup they do.